# Is this JavaScript unit testable using Jasmine?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

Is this javascript code unit testable using Jasmine. If not how do we make it unit testable?

The problem basically is the `helloworld` function is not accessible inside a test spec js file, since it is not in global scope. How do we refactor the code such that it is accessible within the test spec file?

```
(function($){
    function helloWorld() {
          return "Hello world!";
        }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot test a function that is not visible.

You should conditionally export it in your test environment by defining some global constant:

```
(function ($) {
  var exports = window.TESTING ? window : {}

  exports.helloWorld = function () {
    // ...
  };

})(jQuery);
```